# How to remove Chrome browser's default favicon?

Tags: webbrowser-control, browser-cache, favicon

Is it possible to remove Google Chrome's default favicon, such as this one:


[image]

I found an article says it is related to security of the connection of the website. Can I remove it with javascript codes or maybe I can just upload a transparent favicon to disguise it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a favicon that is totally transparent like [this one](https://pasteboard.co/Hh9Z4DB.x-icon).

Just use this one in your page with this piece of HTML:

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
```